# Where do automorphic Maass forms come from?

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-program

I know the Langlands program for GL2/SL2 gives some hints as to the origins of automorphic representations, and that some cases of the correspondence have been completely classified or reasonably worked out, e.g. the discrete series representations and principal series of eigenvalue 1/4. My question is whether there is any conjecture regarding the origins of principal series of eigenvalues greater than 1/4?

Comment: I assume this question may be relevant to post in mathoverflow

Comment: I am a novice on this topic, but I believe that the "remaining cases" of Langlands for $GL_2(\mathbb Q)$, i.e. Maass forms with eigenvalue $>1/4$ are suspected to not exist in the first place, as no interesting arithmetic correspondence or conjecture would even utilize them.

Comment: Can you state your question more precisely?  Are you asking something related to [Selberg's eigenvalue conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg%27s_1/4_conjecture)?

Comment: No, my question is unrelated to the Selberg eigenvalue conjecture. I am asking essentially if the automorphic L-functions coming from spherical Maass forms of eigenvalues $1/4 + t^2$ where $t^2 > 0$ have any conjectural arithmetic origins, such as the L-function of certain field extensions.

Comment: Too complicated for me but some keywords are mentioned [there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/127251/84768) (in Joel's answer and comments, but read Marc's one first)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was looking for.